# I can't find the generated AWS Bitnami Ubuntu server password inside instance system logs. Why generated password is not showing up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-platform, bitnami

I am trying to connect Bitnami Parse server in AWS EC2 cloud Ubuntu instance using Putty in windows.
Bitnami dashboard is asking for username and password.
Default username I entered user and tried to get password in instance system log file but could not find it.Please help me to get the password.
Thanks

[image: Instance System log snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Developer here,

Access your instance via SSH, and execute the following command:

```
sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/log/pre-start.log | grep "Bitnami application password"
```

The default user is `user`.

I hope it helps